# Ajax request after success result of other reqjest (.NET + jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to get xml document from a server, then client signs it and sends back to server.

At server side I have web method which saves document:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SaveSignedDocument(string SignedData)
{
    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms();
    ....
}
```

Then, I get document from a server and after success receive it I make client to sign it and send back. Here is Javascript

```
// get xml to sign
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetXMLReceipt",
        data: "{'ITN': " + ITN + " }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            // xml file was got
            var xmlString = xmlToString(xmlData);
            // Sign data
            var SignedData = SignData(xmlString);

            // Send it to server
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Default.aspx/SaveSignedDocument',
                data: "{ 'SignedData': '" + SignedData + "' }",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data){
                    alert('Document was successfully sent!');
                }
                error: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                    alert('Send signed data failed - ' + jqXHR);
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            alert('Get data failed - ' + jqXHR);
        }
    });
```

The problem is that none of the alert at second requests ever fire. If I change request to synchronous everything is ok but why it does not work like written above? The server receives nothing and if we look to network traffic I see that request was interrupted. Why?

Comment: Try `Content-Type: text/html` when posting JSON data as a string.

Comment: Did not help. Moreover it seems that sometimes async answer (sussess and error) never comes at both requests. If I make both requests sync everything works always... And I can't really understand why. 
I thought that maybe there is trouble at server code but I put all block of webmethod inside try{}catch{} and result is always be returned. So I can't understand why sometimes nothing happends if I click a link what have to execute that javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode your data properly, do not use any string concatenations. Here's the correct way:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ ITN: ITN }),
```

and on your second AJAX request:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ SignedData: SignedData })
```

The `JSON.stringify` method will ensure that you are sending valid JSON to your server by properly encoding the argument.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I used JSON.stringify() at both requests but result unfortunately is the same. First request is sent, success function of it is run but success function of second request never fires and I do not see at IE final alert. 
At VS2010 debugger Webmethod() for second request is not called.  But if I add async:false to both requests everything works perfect...

Comment: Where are you trigerring those AJAX requests? If this is inside the click handler of some button you might need to return false at the end from this handler to cancel the default action from this link.

Comment: It looks that there is a solution. I forget to return false! Thanks a lot :)